# compare two classes c#

Tags: c#, class, compare

I need to determine if two classes have the same value.

Class A is the model of a record in a database.
The value of Class A is set as values of textboxes in a form.

If save is triggered,
I need to know if values on the textboxes are still the same as Class A.

I created Class B and equals it to class A.
Then replace Class B attribute values to what the textboxes has.

Then I compare if `Class A == Class B`.

My Problem is that after I update an attribute of Class B, the same attribute from Class A updates.

what can you suggest.

Comment: Do you really mean _classes_ and not _objects_?

Comment: How are you creating class B? Are they really two different classes or just two different instances of the same class?

Comment: I declare two classes. The set value on the first class upon the form load, I then set value on the second class upon trigger at save.

Comment: You should add some code: the definitions of your two classes and the part where you assign and compare values.

Comment: Why you aren't using immutable class?

Comment: Do you mean object a and object b instead of class a and class b?

Answer (score 1):

Consider turning your classes into structs so that they're copied by value, not by reference.

That way, if you do `var b = a`, the values inside `a` are literally copied over to `b` so that changing one will not affect the other. Then, you can just do `a == b` and it will automatically work by default. (Keep in mind -- if you have a huge amount of data inside your object instance, and you copy it many times, it could slow down your program/take up a lot of memory!)

---

Alternatively, implement the [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface, which requires you to implement a `clone` method.That way, you can do `var b = a.clone();` rather then `var b = a;`. The `clone` method should instantiate a new version of your class and manually copy data over so that the two variables refer to different instances rather then the same one.

If you take this route, you probably need to implement custom equality comparators (see the [IEquatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) interface).

Answer (score -2):

Create a new object for class B Which has a Copy of class A

Example:

```
classA objA= new classA();    
classA objB= new classA();    
objB=ObjA;
```

now Both Instances are different